# Minimizing Disk Space for CentOS & Vagrant VM Install

Tags: centos, virtualization, puppet, vagrant

I'm working on building a Base VM for use with a Vagrant, and/or Puppet.

I've done the minimal CentOS 6.3 install 32 bit. It's still a size of approx 800 mb.  From what I've found out there people have built out base vm's with approx 300 mb disk.  I've cleared the yum cache.   I see a lot of locale data, but I'm not sure if I should remove them because ultimately this will web development and internationalization might be needed.

Anyone have  some tips to help me?  I'm not finding alot.

Please note: There's no desktop installed.

Comment: Does disk space on that scale really matter?  If we assume cloud pricing and a couple backups you are only talking about $2-3 dollars for 1GB for a year.  Surely your time is more valuable, and you should spend it worrying about other things.

Comment: The only reason, I worry about diskspace is for download reasons.  Not so much cost.  1 GB installs might be pretty slow DLing.

Comment: If you are not ecessarily insisting on CentOS, you might want to give [SUSE Studio](http://susestudio.com/) a try.

Comment: @peterph that's pretty sweet, I'm playing with it right now.  Sadly the prod environment is typically RHEL, so it's better to go with CENTos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some prebuilt Vagrant box files for Centos 6.3 here:

http://www.vagrantbox.es/

Ranging form 310-610MB. I was like you and built my own at first (what a pain), the file size was fairly large and I hadn't even installed Puppet and other tools yet. Went ahead and downloaded one of these above and it was rock solid.

Comment: I've actually switched to using veewee it's got a great assortment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be worried about space or overhead. But if you are, the minimal install image is the right approach.

You mention download time. Downloading from where? If you're deploying multiple systems, it may make sense to create your own local YUM repository in your environment or use a deployment tool like [Cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/) to handle the installations (and bootstrap Puppet).

Comment: I've actually switched to using veewee it's got a great assortment.